# time scheduler in Drupal block

Tags: drupal, blogs

I have created block in Drupal. this is working fine but now i want some more feature in this. i want to add start date and end date in this. so admin can set the duration for blog. the blog should display on start date and it will stop display  on end date.

Is there any custom module for this. or there is any another way by which i can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Views and CCK. Make a content type with start and end date fields, and then filter the View by start and end date. You can create a block display of the View, which sounds like what you want to do.